# Transformation for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ B^T & C
\end{bmatrix}$. I want to find a matrix $Y$ such that $Y^T X Y = Z$ where 
$$Z =
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 &\ldots &0 &B &0 & \ldots &0
\\ \vdots & 0 & \ldots &\vdots  & 0 &\vdots & \ldots &0
\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots &0  & 0&0 & \ldots &0
\\ B^T & 0  &\ldots &0  & C&0 & \ldots &0
\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots &0  & 0&0 & \ldots &0
\\ \vdots & 0 & \ldots &\vdots  & 0&\vdots & \ldots &0
\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots &0  & 0&0 & \ldots &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try $$Y=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & I & 0 & \ldots & 0\end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: Yes, I just tried to solve the matrix equation for $Z =\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 & B & 0 \\ 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\ B^T &0 & C &0 \\ 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the solution has the form you mentioned. Thanks :)